# String Manipulation to Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have extracted the text from a Credit Card Statement, sliced for only the transactions within the entire month, and saved that within a list.  The list is 404 strings long, and an excerpt of that list is shown below:

```
['Apr',
 '27',
 'UBER',
 'TECHNOLOGIES',
 'INC866-576-1039CA',
 '$10.93',
 'Apr',
 '27',
 'UBER',
 'TECHNOLOGIES',
 'INC866-576-1039CA',
 '$11.38',
 'Apr',
 '28',
 'COSTCO',
 'WHSE',
 '#1018HOUSTONTX',
 '$105.02']
```

As you can see, the list follows a standard format where one transaction is comprised of 3 pieces: the Date (2 separate strings), the Description (2-5 strings), and the Amount (1 string).

My goal is to create a Pandas Dataframe based upon this information, but I am having trouble figuring out a way to manipulate the strings to properly segment each category (Date, Description, Amount).  I believe I need to use some combination of a Regex and a loop to accomplish this.

Per comments, The raw data that is extracted from the credit card statement (PDF) is also show below:

`"   \nApr 27\nUBER TECHNOLOGIES\nINC866-576-1039CA\n$10.93\nApr 27\nUBER TECHNOLOGIES\nINC866-576-1039CA\n$11.38\nApr 28\nCOSTCO WHSE #1018HOUSTONTX\n$105.02\n"`

Comment: What does the original data look like?  Is it a CSV file?  A PDF?  HTML?  Can you show a small example of the original, raw input (with no processing done by you at all)?

Comment: You can use list slicing to combine list elements together

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is to fix it when you parse the raw data. Please show a sample of the raw data that you parsed to get these two records.

Comment: @JohnZwinck the original data is a PDF. An actual credit card statement.  The raw input looks something like this: "  \nApr 27\nUBER TECHNOLOGIES\nINC866-576-1039CA\n$10.93\nApr 27\nUBER TECHNOLOGIES\nINC866-576-1039CA\n$11.38\nApr 28\nCOSTCO WHSE #1018HOUSTONTX\n$105.02\n"

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have provided a sample of the raw data in a response above.  I trust this is what you are referring to.  I used PyPDF2 .extractText() to read

Comment: Post it in your question.

Comment: @cricket_007 I’m unfamiliar with this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply work with the original raw text, which as per your comment is:

```
Apr 27
UBER TECHNOLOGIES
INC866-576-1039CA
$10.93
Apr 27
UBER TECHNOLOGIES
INC866-576-1039CA
$11.38
Apr 28
COSTCO WHSE #1018HOUSTONTX
$105.02
```

It appears that the format is:

```
DATE
VENDOR
[EXTRA INFO, OPTIONAL]
$AMOUNT
```

You can read the lines in a loop, something like this:

```
txs = []
for line in file:
    date = pd.to_datetime(line)
    vendor = next(file)
    amount = next(file) # might not be amount yet
    while not amount.startswith('$'):
        vendor += amount
        amount = next(file)
    txs.append((date, vendor, amount))

# now create DataFrame
pd.DataFrame(txs)
```

The idea here is to read the file in chunks, with one iteration of the loop per transaction.

Comment: This is my first stackoverflow question and I am blown away with the quickness and overall response of the community, especially John.  Thank you - I will utilize this and make it work.  Really appreciate your expertise.

Comment: @Ryan: If it helped you, consider accepting it - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more details.